# Plot hyperbola equation in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble plotting hyperbolas in `R`. It works with

```
f <- function(x,y) x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20
```

but the equation that I have doesn't work like this. Do you know how to plot the hyperbola below in `R`?

[image: Hyperbola]

Comment: The function that I mentioned "f <- function(x,y) x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20" is from your link, it works fine. But the function that I've a screenshot of, doesn't work that way.

Comment: Please edit your question, because I could not understand whether you want to plot the function which you wrote or you have given the screenshot. For me its not clear. Also avoid giving pictures/screenshot . Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: You can modify your function to be f <- function(x,y) ((sqrt((95-x)^2 - (0-y)^2) -  sqrt((0-x)^2 - (0-y)^2)) - 0.4829)